# Add Azure Login to .Net 4.5 Webforms Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory

We Currently have a Web Forms ASPX application I am trying to add Azure Authentication as a login option to. I don't currently want to rewrite the application as a MVC application.

I have added a Startup.cs file to the application as well as Microsoft.Owin.Security, Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies, Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect. Currently the application uses forms based authentication but I would like to add Azure as a login type and will keep track of what type of login they are using with a variable so the application will know how to login them out. I can't seem to get it to send me to the Microsoft common login page. Does anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong to get this to work?

If I view the context from the button after it runs the response is a 401 but if I use the same client ID, and use the Microsoft Azure provided Sample it will log me in using the sample application so i know the Application is set up correctly on the Azure Portal.

In my Startup.cs I have:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Notifications;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(ClientDevicesManagement.Startup))]

namespace ClientDevicesManagement
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // The Client ID (a.k.a. Application ID) is used by the application to uniquely identify itself to Azure AD
        string clientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];

        // RedirectUri is the URL where the user will be redirected to after they sign in
        string redirectUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["redirectUrl"];

        // Tenant is the tenant ID (e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com, or 'common' for multi-tenant)
        static string tenant = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"];

        // Authority is the URL for authority, composed by Azure Active Directory endpoint and the tenant name (e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com)
        string authority = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"], tenant);

        /// <summary>
        /// Configure OWIN to use OpenIdConnect 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app"></param>
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    RedirectUri = redirectUrl,

                    // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUrl,

                    //Scope is the requested scope: OpenIdConnectScopes.OpenIdProfileis equivalent to the string 'openid profile': in the consent screen, this will result in 'Sign you in and read your profile'
                    Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,

                    // ResponseType is set to request the id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
                    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,

                    // ValidateIssuer set to false to allow work accounts from any organization to sign in to your application
                    // To only allow users from a single organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and 'tenant' setting in web.config to the tenant name or Id (example: contoso.onmicrosoft.com)
                    // To allow users from only a list of specific organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and use ValidIssuers parameter
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false
                    },

                    // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                    }
                }
            );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handle failed authentication requests by redirecting the user to the home page with an error in the query string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
        {
            context.HandleResponse();
            context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
}
```

In my login.aspx I have added a asp button that runs this in the code behind:

```
protected void btn_azure_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
        new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
        OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
}
```

web.config is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <REMOVED DB STINGS>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientId" value="REMOVED CLIENT ID" />
    <add key="RedirectUrl" value="http://localhost:44463/" />
    <add key="Tenant" value="common" />
    <add key="Authority" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="59"></sessionState>
    <!--<trust level="full"/>-->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <!-- other configuration sections -->
    <!--TEMPTEST-->
    <siteMap defaultProvider="default">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="admin" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/sitemaps/admin.sitemap" />
        <add name="operation" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/sitemaps/operation.sitemap" />
        <add name="tech" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/sitemaps/tech.sitemap" />
        <add name="vendor" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/sitemaps/vendor.sitemap" />
        <add name="default" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/sitemaps/default.sitemap" />
        <add name="user" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/sitemaps/user.sitemap" />
      </providers>
    </siteMap>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".tgcpauth" defaultUrl="~/default.aspx" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network host="aspmx.l.google.com" userName="REMOVED" password="REMOVED" port="25" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
    <settings>
      <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
  <location path="styles/login.css">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Refering to this [guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect/), I'm willing to bet you're Azure AD is configured to use login URL of the sample app instead of your app and that is what's causing the 401. You can change the app registration though. Inside your application registration, click Manifest.

[image: Azure AAD App Registration Settings]

Make sure that homepage and replyURLs match the URL of your web project settings and save.

[image]

Also, feel free to update your tenant from common to `<your azure tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com`. You'll find this value the Settings > Properties > App ID URI